# How to build a query to Mongo with i18n?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using i18n-node in my express app and i need to get data from database with `getLocale()` "prefix"

**updated question**

My mongoose Schema

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
   Schema = mongoose.Schema; 
   var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
      title: {
        en : {type: String},
        it : {type: String},
        fr : {type: String},                 
          },
    content: {
        en : {type: String},
        it : {type: String},
        fr : {type: String},                 
          },
```

MyController

```
  exports.list = function (req, res) {
       var locale = i18n.getLocale();
       console.log('locale',locale); //working -> en

     Article.find({'title.locale':locale}).sort('-created').populate('user',    'displayName').exec(function (err, articles) {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(400).send({
      message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
    });
  } else {
    console.log('articles',articles,'res');
    res.json(articles);
  }
});
};
```

I want to get all articles with `en`(e.g) prefix.
`getLocale()` method returns a locale like `en`,`it` etc.
 How can i build a query "Find all articles where "title (or content) : getLocale()"  ?
Even `Article.find({'title': 'en'})` not working

Comment: The return value of `getLocale()` is something like `{en: 'titleA'}` or `{it: 'itaB', en: 'titleB'}`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's hard to fetch a subdocument using its key field alone.You need to provide a value of the subdocument eg `Article.find({'title.en' : 'sample' })` . [Update]

I hope this will fix your problem

```
var locale = getLocale();//get locale  returns it, en
var query = {
  'title.'+locale:{ $exists : true, $ne : null }
}
Article.find(query, function(err, articles) {
  console.log(articles);
});
```

Comment: Can you try `Article.find({'title.en':{ $exists : true, $ne : null }})` instead of Article.find({'title': 'en'})